# How to run Python or C# as alternative to VBScript as automation engine

Tags: python, c#, visual-c++, automation, iactivescript

For many years we have been developing an application with Visual C++ and MFC.
The application itself has no technical flow logic, but functions as a com-server. After initialisation, the programme starts the Windows VBScript engine, which in turn controls the flow of the programme through VBScript code.
To start VBScript, the classes `IActiveScriptParse` or `IActiveScript` are used.

Since VBScript has not been developed further by MS for years, I am afraid that in a few years the scripting host will disappear completely from Windows, which would be the ultimate disaster. Therefore, I would like to change the scripting to either Python or C#.

How can I start a Python script or a C# Dll method from the C++ program?
Are there implementation of `IActiveScriptParse` / `IActiveScript` for C#/Python?

Comment: Don't think Python is very good as a scripter since only one instance of Python can run whereas with VBscript several interpreters can be instantiated running different scripts in the same process.